# Javascript equivalent of Rails try method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails I can do this:

```
 x = user.try(:name)
```

this method returns `nil` if `user` is `nil` else `user.name`. Here `name` is a method defined on the `user` object.

I know it can be done using `if..then..else` in Javascript but is there an equivalent **compact** method to do the same in Javascript?

Googling points to Javascript's `try` command which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Checkout this question, lots of good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly it's not the same thing, the Elvis operator would be doing `user.name  || "..."` for instance. But user could be `nil / undefined` so this could throw an error. Here `user.try(:name) / user&.name` is equivalent to `(user || {}).name` as pointed out in the answers

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly to be fair, it mentions the Safe Navigation Operator / Existential Operator `?.` (or `&.` in ruby) that CoffeeScript implements

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

Comment: This link should also be relevant here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Optional Chaining Operator

Is [a new proposal for ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

It is in an early stage but we can start using it with babel.

This is the problem:

```
const person = {name: 'santiago'}
let zip = person.address.zip // Cannot read property 'zip' of undefined
```

This is how it works:

```
const person = {name: 'santiago'}
let zip = person?.address?.zip // undefined
```

To start using it we need babel alpha 7:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli@7.0.0-alpha.19
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining@^7.0.0-alpha.13.1
```

And we need to add the plugin to our .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-optional-chaining"]
}
```

[Adam Bene Medium Post which explains how to use it and another use cases](https://blog.benestudio.co/optional-chaining-operator-in-javascript-342082de2db)

Answer (score 49):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Examples:

```
// Access Properties

user?.name; // user might be null/undefined

user.name?.firstName // user will be available however name is not guaranteed.

// Access array values

addresses?.[index]; // array addresses might be undefined

// May be function??

user.getGeolocation?.(); // If the function exists execute it.
```

Slightly unrelated but something around handling of null/undefined is another feature called [Nullish coalescing operator ??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
// Example:


function foo(input) // some Array as input {
   //.. Some stuff
   return [input??[]].concat(bar); //if input is empty ignore and concat bar on an empty array and return.
}

//----

const defaultVal = 'someVal';
...
const val = this.someObj.prop1??defaultVal;
```

---

*Below is the outdated solution prior to Optional chaining became native to Javascript:*

---

You can do this way, as there is no built in way of doing that:

```
var x = (user || {}).name;
```

- If user is not defined/null you will get undefined
- If user is defined you will get the name property (which may be set or undefined).

This won't break the script if user is not defined (null).

*But user variable has to be declared some where in the scope, even though its value is not defined. Otherwise you will get the err saying user is not defined.*

Similarly if is in global scope then you can explicitly check for this variable as a property of global scope, to avoid the error as mentioned above

ex:

```
 var x = (window.user || {}).name; // or var x = (global.user || {}).name;
```

For safe execution of functions,

```
 var noop = function(){}; //Just a no operation function

 (windowOrSomeObj.exec || noop)(); //Even if there is no property with the name `exec` exists in the object, it will still not fail and you can avoid a check. However this is just a truthy check so you may want to use it only if you are sure the property if exists on the object will be a function.
```

Comment: God mode ON! Thanks! :)

Comment: how about typescript? ;D

Answer (score 8):

You can use logical AND (`&&`) operator. It works differently than in most of the languages because its result is **not a boolean**. For example:

```
const x = user && user.name;
```

The table below shows all possible outcomes of using this operator:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+
|    user      | x = user && user.name |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| undefined    | undefined             |
| null         | null                  |
| {}           | undefined             |
| {name:''}    | ''                    |
| {name:'Jon'} | 'Jon'                 |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that the same as what this gives you in Javascript:

```
user['name']
user.name
```

This returns `undefined` instead of `nil` but that's equivalent in most cases. I think the reason Rails needs the `try` method is because you cannot access instance variables unless they are made accessible.

To add to @PSL's approach, I usually do something like:

```
var x = user || {},
    y = x.name || {},
    z = y.first_name;
```

Comment: I am looking to call methods on the object e.g. `str.match(/\d/)`

Comment: I believe Rails uses try because everything is a method. user['name'] will return an accessor 'name', but won't return the method 'name' on the user instance.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails4, [`try` does this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

> Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like `public_send` does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns nil rather than raising an exception.

In Rails3, `try` is like [`try!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21) in Rails4 and that's the same as `try` except that it complains if the object doesn't understand the method you're trying to call. The original intent of `try` was to hide a bunch of `nil` checks so that you could say:

```
o.try(:m)
```

instead of

```
o.nil?? nil : o.m
```

The Rails4 version also hides a check if the object understands the method you want to call.

There's no special syntax for this in JavaScript but you can sweep the ugliness into a function.

The Rails4 version of `try` would look like this function in JavaScript:

```
function rtry(obj, m) {
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    if(typeof obj[m] === 'function')
        return obj[m].apply(obj, [].slice.call(arguments, 2));
    return null;
}
```

and you'd say things like `x = rtry(obj, 'method_name', arg1, arg2, ...)` and `x` would be `null` if `obj` didn't understand `method_name` (including if `obj` is `null` or `undefined`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BjgjL/

A Rails3 version is simple, that's just a `null` check:

```
function rtry(obj, m) {
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    return obj[m].apply(obj, [].slice.call(arguments, 2));
}
```

and JavaScript itself will raise an exception of `obj` doesn't have an `m` method. This version is equivalent to the "is it a function" version of CoffeeScript's `?` existential operator.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FQCS2/

---

As usual, things might not work out so well if you're dealing with native methods rather than methods that you've written in JavaScript. `typeof (6).toString` might be `'function'` in one JavaScript environment but I don't think it is guaranteed to always be `'function'` everywhere. The primary use (i.e. hide `null` and `undefined` checks) should work everywhere though.

Comment: thanks did not know about the difference in Rails 4 for try method

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Why not roll your own? Not exactly equivalent but does the job.

```
function tryMe(obj) {
  return obj === null || obj === undefined ? null : obj;
}
```