# Avoid declaring large object in getDefaultProps prior to an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The title might not be the best way to describe the problem, but I was wondering if there was a better practice to declaring an object in `getDefaultProps`?

In my `render` method I call several keys from from a prop/state that get updated on a click event i.e. `this.props.player.name`. The problem is that on page load `this.props.player` is blank and calling `.name` errors out. I know I can do something like ...

`getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      player: {
        name: null,
        team: null
        position: null
      }
    };
  }`

but it doesn't feel right. I was hoping there might be something similar to how Ruby does `.try()` where it won't try to call a method on a undefined prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specifically that `this.props.player` is `undefined`, if you define an empty object it will prevent the error from occurring. It's not bad practice to stub out the keys you're anticipating, but setting the default value to `{}` will be enough to prevent it from throwing.

Comment: But getting this.props.player.name will throw you exactly "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined", no?

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I thought so too but it does work for one level down. So when I declare `player: {}`, this returns with no error `this.props.player.name` but something like this `this.props.player.first_name` errors out.

Comment: Yep, it's throwing because you're trying to reference a property on `undefined`. If it's an object, trying to get properties that don't exist off an object is just `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your data from ImmutableJS. Then you can get any part of your data like this:

```
this.state.getIn(['player', 'name', ...])
```

or

```
this.state.get('player')
```

This will not throw error even player is not defined or other, it will return undefined (or null) I don't remember

The update and updateIn work the same

see the doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)

Comment: If he's already using ImmutableJS sure, but this would be a bad reason to add ImmutableJS.

Comment: Immutable or another lib is a part of all good practices of doing react, why not starting using it?

Comment: Using it to solve this problem is massive overkill. Adding a dependency you don't understand because it happens to solve a trivial problem with a simpler solution isn't good practice.

Comment: It looks a good library I might add it at some point, but I agree with Carl in that its a bit overkill for this specific problem. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It's good when you're trying to optimize, it makes it much easier to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` if you can guarantee that your objects are immutable. I personally don't use it because it's possible to get those same guarantees just by using good practices in plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add this vanilla JS solution too - `var x = (user || {}).name;`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285523/772309)