# Javascript OR statement on call function from object

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'll like to see if there is a name(it's a bad practice?) for this:

```
var callback = function(error, data) {
    var method = error ? 'handleError' : 'handleSuccess';
    object[method](error || data, action);
};
```

If there's an error, object.handleError will use *error* and *action*, let say I dont care about any other param after *error*  if *error*

In the other hand, if there's no error, object.handleSuccess will use *data* and *action*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [null-coalescing (Elvis) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6613952/2033671). It's not bad practice but in this case I think it is cleaner to write out the if/else since you are doing the comparison check twice anyways. This way you can omit the second param too.

```
var callback = function(error, data) {
    if(error){
        object.handleError(error);
    else{
        object.handleSuccess(data,action);
    }
};
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, his intention is to ONLY pass along the error object in the first case, and ignore the remaining arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Austin, just to remove the else statement, you think it will be better 
`var callback = function(error, data) {
    if(error){
        return object.handleError(error);
    }
    return object.handleSuccess(data,action);
};`