# Save 'dot' notation?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering whether in newer versions of javascript there is an alternative way of the dot notation which returns an object like nil, but still can use other .dot elements. I have code like this:

```
 var a = venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].prefix;
```

and I get an error like

```
Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

and looking for something similar to

```
if (venues.photos && venue.photos.groups && venue.photos.groups[0].items ) {
  a=venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].prefix;
} else {
  a=null;
}
```

For those who know objective C i would like something of the Form:

```
NSObject * val = [[a b] c] .. n]
```

Comment: you could use a try/catch block - even in the ye olde javascript

Comment: how does a, b, c, and n in the objective C example relate to the question? - as you go 6 levels deep in javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX that's just because objective-c never checks if the receiver of a message exists, and this notation can be used to access properties via their generated getters. some would argue it is a flaw of the language. what you are looking for is closer to Swifts optionals.

Comment: or the existential or elvis operator in various languages, for example coffeescript.

Comment: @njzk2 - nevermind - it would've been interesting to see how the parts in Obective C relate to the code in javascript, I understand (by inference as I've never touched Objective C, but I'm clever enough to infer) what the code does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs#get) from [lodash](https://lodash.com)

Their example code:

> var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
>
> _.get(object, 'a[0].b.c'); // → 3
>
> _.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']); // → 3
>
> _.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default'); // → 'default'

So you can do

```
var a = _.get(venue, 'photos.groups[0].items[0].prefix');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. 
There is no feature like that you want in ES6 neither ES7
http://es6-features.org/#Constants

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var defaultObject = "";    //this is the default value returned if the property is not found, you can return an empty object like {} too
Object.prototype.get = function(name) {
    if (this != undefined && this[name] != undefined)
        return this[name];
    else
        return defaultObject;
}
Object.prototype.defaultTo = function(value) {
    if (this === defaultObject)
        return value;
    else
        return this;
}
```

Usage:

```
var venue = { photos: { groups: [] } };
var a = venue.get("photos").get("groups").get(0).get("items").get(0).get("prefix").defaultTo("No prefix found");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering whether in newer versions of javascript there is an alternative way of the dot notation which returns an object like nil, but still can use other .dot elements.

No, there is nothing like this. [There have been discussions](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator) about such an operator for ES7, but there was no consensus.

Answer (score 0):

With Modern Javascript you can do it :

```
var a = venue?.photos?.groups?.[0].items?.[0].prefix;
```