# How do I write this php array function in JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is working great in PHP, how can I accomplish the same in JS/jQuery?

```
$statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] = ($statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] ?? 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Any other html/js code?

Comment: No, I just want to figure out how I can do it in JavaScript with same variable/array names? Does JS/jQuery have something similar to the PHP  null coalesce operator?

Comment: Question already exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @JohnnyDew Thanks! Like this? `var statsArr['Status'][s_id]['count'] = statsArr['Status'][s_id]['count'] + 1 || 0` It gave me `missing ; before statement`

Comment: I removed var and it didn't give me the error but now I get this `TypeError: statsArr.Status is undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define each array as an array. Then you won't have the `missing ; before statement` error.

```
var s_id = 0;
var statsArr = Array();
statsArr['Status'] = Array();
statsArr['Status'][s_id] = Array();
statsArr['Status'][s_id]['count'] = statsArr['Status'][s_id]['count'] + 1 || 0;
// the result will be 0 since statsArr['Status'][s_id]['count'] was not defined previously
```