# Javascript Variable checking shorthand

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a shorthand way to write something like this in JavaScript

```
if (thingExists) {
    thingExists.manipulate
}
```

I think I remember seeing something along the lines of

```
thingExists?.manipulate
```

but that may have been TypeScript or something.

Anyway, any knowledge on that matter is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? How do you want to use such a construct? Is `thingExists.manipulate` supposed to be a value of a property or a function call?

Comment: You can short circuit it with `&&`. `thingExists && thingExists.manipulate`, although it's not that readable.

Comment: Yes, JS doesn’t have `?.` yet. There are [proposals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286392/4642212) for this.

Comment: @Xufox you mean `?:` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` for short circuiting:

```
    thingExists && thingExists.manipulate
```

`thingExists.manipulate` will be evaluated if and only if `thingExists` is truthy.

**Example:**

```js
var obj = { func: function() { console.log("func is called"); } };

obj && obj.func();                        // => func is called 

var falsy = null;

falsy && falsy.imaginaryFunc();           // => nothing
```