# How to check if a "deep" structure is not undefined?

Tags: javascript

what is the best aproach to check if a "deep" structure is undefined?

For example I have some check like this:

```
if (json.error.message != undefined) {
    console.log(json.error.message);
}
```

The problem here is, that if json.error is already undefined this will crash. So I would need to write something like:

```
if (json.error != undefined && json.error.message != undefined) {
    console.log(json.error.message);
}
```

But this could not be the best aproach or? When I would have even "deeper" structures.

Comment: [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6613952/102937)

Comment: Check this article about `Elvis` operator aka safe navigation operator.https://www.beyondjava.net/elvis-operator-aka-safe-navigation-javascript-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (json?.error?.message != undefined) {
    console.log(json.error.message);
}
```