# fallback for dynamic object using bracket

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

```
const result = something[dynamicValue]
```

Given the above code, I can get error of `Cannot read property 'x' of null` because something is undefined, how do I fallback check to void error? should I do something like this

```
const result = something && something[dynamicValue]
```

Comment: `const result = something?.[dynamicValue]`

Comment: [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)